# How to determine if a point is in shape in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to determine whether a point within a shape.

I found a algorithm that does the job
https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

I tested the algorithm out with a square shape.

total corners of a square = 4

but however it returns me a wrong result.(see my output results below) after my codes

Shape.h

```
#ifndef __Shape__Shape__
#define __Shape__Shape__

class Shape   {


private:
        int xArray[4];
        int yArray[4];
        int x;
        int y;
public:
        bool inPoly(int x,int y);
        void pointInShape();
};

#endif
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include <iostream>

bool Shape::inPoly(int x,int y) {

   xArray[0] = 1;
   xArray[1] = 1;
   xArray[2] = 3;
   xArray[3] = 3;

   yArray[0] = 1;
   yArray[1] = 3;
   yArray[2] = 3;
   yArray[3] = 1;

   int i, j, nvert = 4, c = 0;
   for (i = 0, j = nvert - 1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
       if ( ((yArray[i]>y) != (yArray[j]>y)) &&
           (x < (xArray[j]-xArray[i]) * (y-yArray[i]) / (yArray[j]-yArray[i]) + xArray[i]) )
           c = !c;
   }
   return c;
}


void Shape::pointInShape() {
    std::cout << "results" << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(1,1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(1,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(1,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(2,1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(2,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(2,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(3,1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(3,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << inPoly(3,3) << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   Shape shape;
   shape.pointInShape();
}
```

it returns me this output

```
   results
   1 <-- (means that 1,1 is is within polygon)
   1 <-- (means that 1,2 is is within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 1,3 is is not within polygon)
   1 <-- (means that 2,1 is is within polygon)
   1 <-- (means that 2,2 is is within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 2,3 is is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 3,1 is is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 3,2 is is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 3,3 is is not within polygon)
```

by right the correct output should only return 2,2 as true

correct output

```
   results
   0 <-- (means that 1,1 is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 1,2 is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 1,3 is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 2,1 is not within polygon)
   1 <-- (2,2 is is within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 2,3 is is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 3,1 is is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 3,2 is is not within polygon)
   0 <-- (means that 3,3 is is not within polygon)
```

Any advice/suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

the PNPOLY code as written is really meant for floats not ints. If you defined your arrays and vertices as floats it would give you the expected results.

1.0f and 2.0f are not adjacent in float math, but 1 and 2 are in int math.

what should tip you off is the function prototype

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
```

furthermore the line:

```
(testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
```

is going to truncate your ints to the nearest int after those divides.

If you really want to use ints you would have to define your shapes with a more room, say 100x100 instead of 2x2.

Answer (score 1):

According to your link and this one: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/ (see section 2.03) the algorithm you've used will only work for points in the inside/outside of the polygon. Points on the border may return a 1 or a 0

> If you want to know when a point is exactly on the boundary, you need another program. This is only one of many functions that PNPOLY lacks; it also doesn't predict tomorrow's weather. You are free to extend PNPOLY's source code.